# cannot manipulate response from xmlHttpRequest 2

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, response

I'm using XHR 2 to upload/save files.

According to the response of the server I want to perform an action. For example if the responce is "Saved" I want to hide a div or if the response is "Not Saved" I want to show another div etc...

I implemented what appears to be a simple code that should be working , but is not

Here is the snippet of the XHR

```
    //initialize

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');
          xhr.responseType="text";
          xhr.onload = function() {

                                  //if all ok.... 
                      if (xhr.status === 200)         
                      { 
                                       //update html5 progress bar                                   
                       progress.value = progress.innerHTML = 100;

                                       //get the respnse  
                      var data=xhr.response;

                                      //convert it to sting - kind of overkill, I know, but I'm stack
                           var data2=data.toString();

                                      //alert it -- works    
                      alert('data2     '+data2);



                                 //now, do something, according to the response -- NOT working, never alert anything
                               if (data2=="Not Saved"){alert('Ooops, not saved');}


                                if(data2=="Saved"){alert('It's all good');} 


                              if(data2=="File too big"){alert('hey, you are watching Jake and Amir');}  


                              document.getElementById('imagesaved').innerHTML=data; 


                     } 

//refers to if (xhr.status === 200)               
else {document.getElementById("imagesaved").innerHTML="Connect to server failed";}
```

What is wrong here? This should be working right? Any suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I put the alerts for testing. What I actually want to do is call some functions.

If I put

```
if (data2=="Not Saved"){functionOne();}


if(data2=="Saved"){functionTwo();}  


if(data2=="File too big"){functionThree();}
```

the functions never get called

if I put

```
if (data2!="Not Saved"){functionOne();}


if(data2!="Saved"){functionTwo();}  


if(data2!="File too big"){functionThree();}
```

ALL the functions are called!!!

I still dont get it...Maybe its something with the response? Or the onload function?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

What I  finally did is make the server response with numbers, not text. So encoding  does not matter any more...

This is the code

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
                      if (xhr.status == 200)          
                      {                                      
                      var data=xhr.response;



                              if(data==1) 

         //say to  the user is saved
{document.getElementById('imagesaved').innerHTML="Saved";}  

    //say to the user, there was an error

    else{document.getElementById('imagesaved').innerHTML="Error";}


                                    }         
                        //say to the user that connection to the server failed
                     else {document.getElementById("imagesaved").innerHTML="Cannot connect";}
          };


          xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');
     xhr.send(formData);
```

This is a workaround. I dont know if its the right way to solve this problem , technically. I decided to post it anyway, to help others to quickly solve similar problems. If anyboy else has a better way to suggest , please do.

Answer (score 0):

In this line : `if(data2=="Saved"){alert('It's all good');}`, you have to escape " ' ".
So convert it to : `if(data2=="Saved"){alert('It\'s all good');}`

Are you sure that the response of your ajax is text/plain ?
Look on the console (ctrl+shift+i on chrome, F12 on firefox), on net or network tab.

Look on console tab if you got some javascript errors too.

Comment: @ I've simply replaced `'It's all good'` with `'Good'`, so no need to escape characters...And still nothing. And I dont get any errors in Chrome;s console. Also I put this first `xhr.onload = function() {...}` and then the `xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');` and still nothing....I dont get it...

Comment: What the response of your ajax ? (you can see all of this in "network" tab of the web-dev tools).
Try to alert xhr.status and xhr.response, in all cases. For seeing.

Comment: I alert the status and the response. If everything goes right, I get `200` and `Saved`, but the `Good` never alerts. This is so weird...

Comment: Try this alert(typeof data2);

Comment: DAT error ...
I dont think it's linked to the response or onload function.
I think, it's because of var types. If you alert(typeof data2);, does javascript told you about string ?
Maybe it's because of encoding. In which encoding are your response ?
And your javascript ? You have to be sure it's the same.
You can try to convert everything in unicode.
Try match functions too (if it works you can have same result than with == )

Comment: Yes, the response is a string. But how can I check and edit the encoding?

Comment: Your ajax send a HTTP response.
You have to set HTTP headers. In PHP : header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
The HTTP headers is the firsts lines of your document. If you use another language, just be sure on how you can change it.

About javascript encoding, you have to be sure that your text editor or your IDE writes your files in the same encoding than you HTTP response. I advice you to use UTF-8 (without BOM under windows)

Comment: I put `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` first line in php (server). And th, on the client I put `xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=utf8");` before the onload function. And STILL nothing... I swear Im not doing this on purpose...

Comment: Don't worry, I believe you. I try to help you. I know how informatic can be raging when it decides bugging.
Honestly, I just don't know.
I did so many xhr, working without problem, that bug is SO strange ... I usually use jQuery, but I know JS nativ, and your code should work ...
Good luck!

Comment: Maybe bugs somewhere else in the code...I dont know...By the way, can you suggest an alternative way to manipulate server's response?

Comment: If I were you, I would use jQuery and http://eman1986.github.io/jquery.jUploader/ for doing this kind of things.
But I am used to jQuery ...

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour vos réponses mon ami. (Hope this makes sense, Goolge translate it for me). If you want, check the solution I found...